# How to Xdebug Laravel composer tests

Tags: laravel, docker, sublimetext3, xdebug, lumen

I have Laravel Lumen in Docker container and Sublime Text in OSX host.

I was able to make the Xdebug working when running PHP urls from the browsers,
but how to get it working with scripts run from the docker machine?

I saw that Xdebug was disabled by default in composer, but was able to make env variable to enable it. Still it cannot connect to my Sublime Text's Xdebug plugin.

What are the extra steps to make it work?

php ini:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9002
xdebug.remote_log = /var/www/html/xdebug.log
```

Sublime's Xdebug config:

```
{
    "path_mapping": {
        "/var/www/html" : "/Users/mark/projects/todolist/api/"
    },
    "url": "http://localhost",
    "super_globals": true,
    "close_on_stop": true,
    "port": 9002,
    "debug": true,
    "host":"0.0.0.0"
}
```

Comment: 1) Check Xdebug log and see where and if it tries to connect to 2) Run `php -i` via SSH (or some php script with `phpinfo()` output run via CLI) -- on Linux it's very common to have one php.ini file for Apache/web server and another config file for CLI scripts. It's possible that Xdebug is not enabled for CLI.

Comment: Thank you for your help. xdebug log says that it's trying to connect but cannot.
That's strange because it can connect from normal php when opening a web page.
Host.docker.internal:9002, poll success, but error: operation in progress (29)

Comment: 1) Just in case: please check what other service might be running on OSX on that port -- such error usually indicates that the connection is made.. It's possible that you already have a debug session in progress and Sublime may be supporting only 1 session at a time... 2) What is the actual IP that is used there (where Xdebug tries to connect to) try to resolve it to IPv4 address for both working and not working scenario.

Comment: I have changed the port already to 9002. And both, browser initiated and composer initated works and connects to same.
but the difference is after detecting the only one breakpoint, connection is somehow made again and it works from browser but not from composer

`[66] I: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9002.`
`[66] W: Creating socket for 'host.docker.internal:9002', poll success, but error: Operation in progress (29).`
`[66] E: Could not connect to client. :-(`

Comment: Here are the logs that shows difference between working and not working xdebug:
https://pastebin.com/CmNcFP0s

Comment: Check if Sublime is able to handle more than 1 xdebug session (I think it is not). As far as I can read the log -- Xdebug log shows that in non-working case the previous debug session still remains opened. P.S.Try PhpStorm IDE -- it can work with more than 1 simultaneous xdebug connection (should be set to 3 by default; if not -- change that manually in IDE settings). P.P.S. As to why you have more than 1 connection / why previous one is not fully closed -- must be specific to your code.

Comment: I had a sublime config line "close_on_stop":true, which might have closed the debug.
BUT now I'm at the point that debugging works if I write ./phpunit /var/www/.../index.php BUT it does NOT work when i run composer phpunit.
why is that ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no other ideas.